# Compiled SWF works on the dev machine but does not on other computers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5, compilation

this is really annoying and I haven't found a solution for this.

I have a videochat app (as3) developed in CS5, when I test the movie (ctrl+enter) it compiles and shows no errors, then I upload the file to the server and does not work at all.
the xml paths are perfect, in fact when I go to the page on the machine with FLash CS5 it loads fine, but from  a friend's computer does not work at all.

any information on this? I'm going nuts with this !

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, that's something crazy, on my friend's computer the swf loads and loops non-sense, on my computer loads fine and does not loop like crazy, I'm going to try the firebug thing to see what comes up.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be tough to debug, but I have a couple ideas of things to try.

On your friend's computer:
1) This is kind of a stupid question, but in the interest of throroughness: your friend does have Flash, right? And it's not getting blocked by a browser extension like FlashBlock?

2) As David suggested above, make sure the http requests are successful.  On Google Chrome (Wrench > Tools > Javascript Console), the Console or Network tabs should show you if something is failing to load.  Same thing with Firefox with Firebug installed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Install Firebug (Firefox) and in the "Net" panel, click "All" then reload the flash movie again from the machine that usually fails to load the SWF. Then simply see if anything appears in red color in the Firebug requests list.

Comment: Thanks, here is what happened, there was an error firing up when the user did not have at least 1 camera installed, so that's why I didn't see the crash, I realized after installing win7, Flash CS 5.5, and the webcam was not installed, lol ...  Thanks guys !!